# Add one year to the creation/modification date

Tags: osx, date

I'm trying to add one year to the modification and creation dates to all files of a folder.

I found many examples to modify a whole date (not only the year).

How can I add one year to the creation/modification to all files in a folder?

I'm on OS X.

Comment: Which OS and filesystem are you using? Depending on that, you probably won't be able to modify or even get the creation time.

Comment: @muru I'm on OS X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`touch` has an adjust option (`-A`), but that is sadly limited to 99 hours, 99 minutes, and 99 seconds. But repeated applications can get you what you want:

in Bash:

```
# assume a year is 365 days
for day in {1..365}; do 
    touch -A 240000 folder/* 
done

# on a mac with Xcode cmdline tools installed, 
# set creation time to mtime:
for f in folder/* ; do
    SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m $f)" $f
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm on OS X and this command didn't work :(

Comment: I'm on macOS as well. It works for me. In what way did it not work? Error message?

Comment: My bad : I only typed -A 240000 without the loop. Thank you ! your script is awesome.

Comment: I noticed that only the modification date is modified. How it's possible to modify the creation date as well?

Comment: @oya2020 use `SetFile` for that: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99599/205028

Comment: Thank you didn't know that. Can I add "one year" with SetFile ?

Comment: No. But you can use SetFile to set the creation date to the modification date. Are they the same in your case, or no?

Comment: Yes they are the same

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the SetFile step at the end

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU date, you can try something like

```
for file in *; do echo "$file"  $(date -d "$(date -r $file) 1 year"); done
```

(this really ought to be cleaned up for special characters and formatting)
You're not going to get creation date on most file systems.